# ckEditor not working when place in a Foundation for App Panel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for App and ckEditor to build an Application that means to help people devellop their novel, then write it.

To do so, I've put ckEditor in a Panel that come from the left of the screen when it's call, but I'm getting a "TypeError: a.$.parentNode is null" error in ckEditor

My page being :

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="grid-frame">
        <div zf-panel="" id="editor">
            <textarea name="editorArea" id="editorArea" rows="10" cols="80">
              This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="rightBarController">
          <div ng-show="rightBarVisibility">
            <ul class="vertical primary menu-bar expand" id="rightBar">
              <li><a ui-sref="organigram"><img zf-iconic="" icon="person" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- Persos -->
              <li><a ui-sref="frises"><img zf-iconic="" icon="flag" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- Frises -->
              <li><a ui-sref="articles"><img zf-iconic="" icon="comment-square" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- Articles -->
              <li><a ui-sref="chapitres"><img zf-iconic="" icon="document" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- Chapitres -->
              <li><a><img zf-iconic="" icon="dashboard" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- projets -->
              <li><a ui-sref="about"><img zf-iconic="" icon="action" size="medium" class="iconic-color-primary"></a></li><!-- about-->
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ui-view class="grid-block" style="margin-bottom: 50px"></ui-view>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('editorArea');
</script>
```

How can I get it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the following code to include CKeditor? If not please add this at the top of this file.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Your code is working for me

Comment: Of course I've add the js in the html. It work for you ? In a left zf-panel ?